# Why neovim puts a start (*) before indents?

Tags: vim, neovim

I use css and if I want to use * and then brackets it puts * in every line. This 'feature' works in every file type. How can I turn this off?

```
* {
  *
  * }
```

I asked chatGPT and it said me to change some indent setting in neovim config. It didn't help me.

Comment: 1. See `:help 'formatoptions'` and `:help fo-table`. 2. Screw ChatGPT.